# Unknown option '--no-beep'

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, windows, upgrade

I installed a new version of MySQL server (previously 5.0, now 5.5) and I copied the data folder in to the new one. Now I should perform `mysql_upgrade`. I opened the command prompt (server is located on Windows Server 2012) and used `cd` to get in the bin folder. I wrote the file name to run the upgrade. The result was `mysql_upgrade: unknown option '--no-beep'`. What's that? I tried to do some research on Google, but no one seemed to have the same error.

I'm confused. Even the MySQL documentation doesn't seem to tell anything about the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `no-beep` [option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_no-beep) causes the `mysql` command line client not to beep when errors occur.

If that's an option you want, it should be in the `[mysql]` section of your `my.cnf`.  This error suggests that it's in the `[client]` section of your `my.cnf`, which causes `mysql_upgrade` to throw the error since the option isn't recognized.

Check your `my.cnf` and either remove the line or place it in the `[mysql]` section instead of `[client]` and you should be good.

> The [client] option group is read by all client programs (but not by
>   mysqld). This enables you to specify options that apply to all
>   clients. For example, [client] is the perfect group to use to specify
>   the password that you use to connect to the server. (But make sure
>   that the option file is readable and writable only by yourself, so
>   that other people cannot find out your password.) Be sure not to put
>   an option in the [client] group unless it is recognized by all client
>   programs that you use. Programs that do not understand the option quit
>   after displaying an error message if you try to run them.

-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html